# Removing/Downgrading to older version of ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed ElasticSearch 0.90.10 deb (Using Software Center) without knowing that I needed to use 0.20.6. I have removed directories pertaining to 0.90/0.20 to start off fresh but when I tar -zxvf elasticsearch-0.20.6 and curl the localhost I still get that I'm using v.0.90.10 !

I've tried to do some research on how to remove ES 0.90.10 but nothing has resolved my issue. 
Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you restart the ES service?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't know if it's pertinent but I keep getting stuck on "recovered [0] indices into cluster_state". I made sure to rm -rf elasticsearch-0.90.10 then shut down the service then opened up the terminal and tried again but I keep getting stuck here.

Comment: I have a feeling it didn't completely shutdown and you are still running the initial process started with `0.90.10`. Try killing the service again and make sure it is dead with `ps aux | grep elasticsearch`.  Then remove the old directory and restart the service with the new directory `elasticsearch-0.20.6/bin/elasticsearch`.

Comment: There was nothing to kill and I removed every directory that had elasticsearch and when I go to the Software Center to install the 0.20 deb it still tells me that 0.90 is installed. Any idea how I can just "uninstall" elasticsearch?

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize you installed with the software center.  It probably got baked in pretty well.  You're best off uninstalling through the software center..but I apologize for not having much experience with this (you may want to add it to your question to help people though).

Comment: I'll be sure to edit my question to include it. Thanks for your help though I very much appreciate you taking a crack at it.